# Label both sides in BarChart

Tags: plotting, labeling

I have labeled the name(A,B,C) of each row on the left and value of each item , is there any way to put the total number(6,7,5) of each row on the right side without changing other labels?

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 1}, {3, 1, 1}}, BarOrigin -> Left, 
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked", BarSpacing -> 0.5, 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"A", "B", "C"}, Before], None}, 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#1, Center] &)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
BarChart[#, BarOrigin -> Left, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
 BarSpacing -> 0.5, 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[{{"A", "B", "C"}, {Total@#[[1]], 
 Total@#[[2]], Total@#[[3]]}}, {Before, After}], None}, 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#1, Center] &)] &@{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 1}, {3, 1, 1}}
```

EDIT: slightly cleaner:

```
BarChart[#, BarOrigin -> Left, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
 BarSpacing -> 0.5, 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[{{"A", "B", "C"}, Total@#}, {Before, After}], None}, 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#1, Center] &)] &@{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 1}, {3, 1, 1}}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer is excellent!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - thanks!
#paradox2 - glad it helped!