# Finessing labels in BarChart

Tags: graphics, plotting

`BarChart` is aggravating. Why don't the following correctly display both percentages and labels?

(1)

```
BarChart[{{1,2,3}},
  ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
  ChartLabels -> 
    {Placed[{"17%", "33%", "50%"}, Center, Style[#, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 11]&],
     Placed[{"aa", "bbb", "cccc"}, After, Style[#, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 14]&]},
  AspectRatio -> 2,
  ImageSize -> 100]
```

The text labels are rendered correctly (based on an A to a similar Q by Pinguin Dirk [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17624), turns out that the `After` option left-justifies the text, while numerical parameters don't, even with `TextAlignment -> Left` set in `Style`):

[image: chart with incorrect label display]

I have also tried using `LabelingFunction`:

(2)

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
 ChartLabels -> 
  Placed[{"aa", "bbb", "cccc"}, After, 
   Style[#, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 14] &],
 LabelingFunction -> Placed[{"17%", "33%", "50%"}, Center],
 AspectRatio -> 2, ImageSize -> 100]
```

But it doesn't display *any* numbers:

[image: the labels don't work here, either]

Finally, this works:

(3)

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", ChartLabels -> {
   Placed[{Style[#, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 10] & /@ {"17%", "33%",
        "50%"},
     Style[#, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 14] & /@ {"aa", "bbb", 
       "cccc"}}, {Center, After}]},
 AspectRatio -> 2, ImageSize -> 100]
```

[image: finally, a proper chart!]

Is the syntax in (1) and (2) incorrect, or are those bugs?

Also note that `FontSize` doesn't match. If it is set to the same value for both numerical and text labels, the numerical values look larger. What's going on there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

some thoughts, I hope this is what you are after:

**ad (1):**

It seems (I couldn't find it in the docs) that when you provide a 2-element `List` of `ChartLabels`, the first element in a stacked `BarChart` is treated as a label for a (stacked) bar, the second one is then the intra-bar-label, so to speak. You can view this here:

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 2}}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
   ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"17%", "33%", "50%"}, Center, 
   Style[#, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 11] &], 
   Placed[{"aa", "bbb", "cccc"}, After, 
   Style[#, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 14] &]}, AspectRatio -> 2, 
   ImageSize -> 150]
```

[image]

You can see that the percentages are now labeling the stacked bars. Not what you want.

If you only provide one set of `Placed` labels, these will be positioned within the bars (what we want). Thus, to get the desired result, we have to provide a 1-element (nested) `List`. To get it working, we have to **make sure** we provide the "Position" (`Center`, `After`,...) also as a `List`, so that Mathematica knows how to treat the nested `ChartLables`, exactly as you did in version (3).

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
   ChartLabels -> {Placed[{{"17%", "33%", "50%"}, {"aa", "bbb", 
   "cccc"}}, {Center, After}, 
   Style[#, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 11] &]}, AspectRatio -> 2, 
   ImageSize -> 100]
```

[image]

I think this is about as clean as it can get and the `FontSize` looks ok to me.

**ad (2):**

If you wanted to use `LabelingFunction`, you have to **provide a function.**

A classical way would be:

```
LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#1, Center] &)
```

(parantheses are important!)

Now it seems that this is a bit tricky to get percentages, as you only have access to the individual labels. One could do something ugly such as:

```
LabelingFunction -> (Placed[{"17%,", "33%", "50%"}[[#2[[2]]]], Center] &)
```

**Add-on**

Now the problem I had when looking at that: using `ChartLabels` one is rather limited, e.g. when plotting several stacked bars. On the other hand, when using `LabelingFunction` one can directly access individual labels, but the totals are harder to get. Hence the following extension is - I hope - helpful:

```
With[{tot = Total /@ #}, 
    BarChart[#, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
       ChartLabels -> Placed[{"aa", "bbb", "cccc"}, After, 
       Style[#, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 11] &],
       LabelingFunction -> (Placed[Round[100 #1/tot[[#2[[1]]]]], Center] &),
       AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 200]] &@{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 3, 3}}
```

[image]

I leave the formatting to you

Answer (score 2):

`BarChart` is tricky...

If you're working with `ChartLayout->"Stacked"` it's better, in my opinion, to put labels and percentages in a `Grid` (or `Column`) format, because occasionally one might need to show overlapping elements. In this case it would be better to adjust you `BarChart` using `BarSpacing` and, maybe, `Opacity`.

However, the trickiest part is really the `LabelingFunction`... Let me show what I've done:

```
Manipulate[
BarChart[{{Ax, Ay, Az}, {Bx, By, Bz}},
TotA := Ax + Ay + Az;
TotB := Bx + By + Bz;
ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
ColorFunction -> u,
BarSpacing -> {0, v},
AspectRatio -> 2,
ImageSize -> 200,
ChartStyle -> Opacity[w],
ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"A", "B"}, Axis], 
Placed[{"x", "y", "z"}, Axis]},
LabelingFunction -> (Placed[
  Grid[{{Style[#3[[2, 1]], Bold, 16, Blue]}, {If[#3[[1, 1]] == "A", 
   Style[N[#1*100/TotA, 3] "%", Red], 
   Style[N[#1*100/TotB, 3] "%", Red]]}}], Center] &)
],
{{Ax, 2, "Ax-value"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{Ay, 5, "Ay-value"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{Az, 4, "Az-value"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{Bx, 6, "Bx-value"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{By, 3, "By-value"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{Bz, 7, "Bz-value"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{v, .5, "BarSpacing"}, -1, 2, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{w, .5, "Opacity"}, 0, 1, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
Button["New Random Color", u = RandomChoice[ColorData["Gradients"]]]]
```

Result:

[image]

Now the same `LabelingFunction`, this time for three bars.

```
Manipulate[
BarChart[{{Ax, Ay, Az}, {Bx, By, Bz}, {Cx, Cy, Cz}},
 TotA := Ax + Ay + Az;
 TotB := Bx + By + Bz;
 TotC := Cx + Cy + Cz;
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
 ColorFunction -> u,
 BarSpacing -> {0, v},
 AspectRatio -> r,
 ImageSize -> s,
 ChartStyle -> Opacity[w],
 ChartElementFunction -> "ObliqueRectangle",
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"A", "B", "C"}, Axis], 
 Placed[{"x", "y", "z"}, Axis]},
 LabelingFunction -> (
 Placed[Grid[{{Style[#3[[2, 1]], Bold, 16, Blue]}, {
     If[#3[[1, 1]] == "A", Style[N[#1*100/TotA, 3] "%", Red], 
      If[#3[[1, 1]] == "B", Style[N[#1*100/TotB, 3] "%", Red], 
       Style[N[#1*100/TotC, 3] "%", Red]]]}}], Center] &)
 ],
{{Ax, 2, "Ax-value"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{Ay, 5, "Ay-value"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{Az, 4, "Az-value"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{Bx, 6, "Bx-value"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{By, 3, "By-value"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{Bz, 7, "Bz-value"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{Cx, 6, "Cx-value"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{Cy, 3, "Cy-value"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{Cz, 7, "Cz-value"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{v, .5, "BarSpacing"}, -1, 2, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{w, .5, "Opacity"}, 0, 1, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{s, 200, "ImageSize"}, 200, 500, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{r, 2, "AspectRatio"}, .5, 3, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
Button["New Random Color", u = RandomChoice[ColorData["Gradients"]]]]
```

Result:

[image]